# Remove gap between rows of flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's my example code:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 350px;
  background: yellow;
}
#wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 10%;
  background: #999;
}

#top {
  flex: 1 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: red;
}

#left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background: blue;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there's a gap (big gray area) between `top` (red) and `left`/`right` (blue/green). Flexbox seems to be spreading everything equally in parent element (gray).

However, I don't want the gap *between* my elements, I need everything to "rise" to top. There can be a gap *after* all elements (at the end).

I tried everything I could find/think of: `auto margins`, `justify-content`, `align-items` etc. No desired effect.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add [`align-content: flex-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) on flex-container or in your case `#wrapper` element.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 350px;
  background: yellow;
}
#wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 10% 50px 10%;
  background: #999;
  align-content: flex-start; /* Add this*/
}
#top {
  flex: 1 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: red;
}
#left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background: blue;
}
#right {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In a multi-line flex row layout, the `align-content` controls how the flex items aligns vertical when they wrap, and since its default is `stretch`, this is expected behavior.

Change it to `align-content: center;` and you'll see how their alignment change to vertical middle.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 350px;
  background: yellow;
}
#wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 10% 50px 10%;
  background: #999;
  align-content: center;
}

#top {
  flex: 1 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}
#right {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```